# Timing python programs

Tags: python

So I am trying to see how long it takes my program to run, and the solution I came  up with is:

```
import datetime

time1 = datetime.datetime.now()

[program code]

time2 = datetime.datetime.now()

print(time2 - time1)
```

I want to know if this is an efficient/correct solution, because all the guides I could find on the internet would use modules such as timeit, etc.

I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Also please [format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that works. However, another solution is:

```
import time

start = time.time()

# do stuff

print(time.time() - start)
```

You could also use `time.clock()` instead of `time.time()`

Comment: Okay, Thanks. Is this method more precise than my solution?

Comment: Both are very precise, you can use whichever one you want.